# How Do I login if I haven't confirmed my email?

Tags: discussion

I know this isn't an RPG question, but I need to know right now.

I made an account on a computer where gmail is blocked and I can't log in.

the tag is irrelavant

Comment: I already know that but I seriously need to know so I can see my questions that actually are about RPGs. Where is the place I ask questions about site problems?

Comment: Use our general meta site for our Q&A network, [meta.se].

Comment: Again, Gmail is blocked and it won't even let me ask a question on the meta unless I'd confirm my email. which I can't do

Comment: No problem! You did the right thing (the only thing you could do), and I've moved the question to the meta side of the site. No harm, and I've posted an answer below that should get you fixed up shortly.

Answer (score 9):

## All is not lost!

If you hadn't registered [your original account](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/27228/warriorking9001) (the one that "owns" all your questions so far), it remains attached to the computer and browser you originally used. That can obviously present difficulties if you don't have access to that machine anymore, if the [browser's cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) have been cleared, or if (as it seems) there is a security block interfering with logging in on that machine.

But you can regain access to that account with some help: someone from Stack Exchange staff (i.e., someone even higher up than a site moderator) can associate the original account with [the account you currently have access to](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/27229/warriorking9001) and merge them together.

You can start this process by following the [instructions on merging accounts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in our Help Center. Since you've used the same email address for both accounts, it should be a speedy process for a staff member to merge them.